# Prevent blank datarow being inserted to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Form with textboxes that inserts data to a datagridview. When I enter data it successfully enters it into the datagridview, this is fine. However, if I close the form without entering data, it inserts a blank row into the datagridview, and then starts a new row underneath it ready to receive more data. How can I prevent it from inserting blank rows?

```
public partial class newquoteForm : Form
{ 
    public newquoteForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public void newquoteForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataRow dr;
        dt.Columns.Add("Item Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Item Description");
        dt.Columns.Add("Retail Price");
        dt.Columns.Add("Cost Price");
        dt.Columns.Add("In Stock");
        dt.Columns.Add("On Jobs");
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;       
    }

    public void addBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        additemForm additemForm = new additemForm();
        additemForm.ShowDialog();
        dt.Rows.Add(additemForm.strItem, additemForm.strDesc, additemForm.strRetail); // some methods are missing, Don't worry about it.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you place breakpoints on the OnClose or OnClosing event as see if some other code is being executed that would cause this also you may want to set the dataGridView1.DataSource = null; in the forms Closing event..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `AddItemForm` has some properties that you use to create a new row when `addBTN_Click` executes. You never check that the `AddItemForm` initialized those properties correctly. You just add the values of those properties all willy-nilly even if those values are empty. I'd add a property to `AddItemForm` like `IsValid` that will only be true when the other properties are initialized correctly. And then check that before creating the new row.

In your AddItemForm:

```
public bool IsValid {
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStrItem.Text) &&
               !string.isNullOrEmpty(your other textboxes)...;
        // I'm just guessing here what controls your form has. you should see the point though
    }
}
```

And then when you create the new row:

```
using (var addItemForm = new AddItemForm()) {
    if (addItemForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        if (addItemForm.IsValid) {
            dt.Rows.Add(additemForm.strItem, additemForm.strDesc, additemForm.strRetail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly apart from you made a minor error (addItemForm.IsValid()) is used like a method, no issue simply removed the () and it works.

Comment: Oh yea nice catch. I also edited it to use a `using` statement to make sure it's properly disposed.

Comment: As in, I open the form, close it, and re-open without the error message "cannot recover disposed object" (or whatever it is!)

Comment: Not quite. In this case you wont every attempt to recover a disposed object because you create a new form and only access the new form in the using statement. I can't give you as good of an explanation as msdn can so check out these links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: if (FORMNAME == null || FORMNAME.IsDisposed == true)
                FORMNAME = new FORMNAME();    works for me

Answer (score 0):

Say I have created a additemForm form with three textboxes and then set the strItem,strDesc and strRetail properties on close of the form. I will also set the Dialog result then :

```
 void additemForm_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        strItem = this.textBox1.Text;
        strDesc = this.textBox2.Text;
        strRetail = this.textBox3.Text;

        //You can check anything here
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strItem))
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
        else
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }
```

Now in the main form, you can check the Dialog result and then act on it:

```
 additemForm additemForm = new additemForm();
        DialogResult dialogResult = additemForm.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(additemForm.strItem, additemForm.strDesc, additemForm.strRetail); // some methods are missing, Don't worry about it.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```